# Accessing constants in LuaJava

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, lua

I am adapting LuaJava to my Android application and would like scripts to run OpenGL functions. I push the GL context to Lua in a function using pushJavaObject and it works. However I cannot use any constants like COLOR_BUFFER_BIT in the GL10 class. Any way to access these? Will I have to copy all the constants over?

This works

```
function onUpdate(gl)
    GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT = 16384
    gl:glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 1)
    gl:glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
end
```

This fails

```
function onUpdate(gl)        
    gl:glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 1)
    gl:glClear(gl:GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
end
```

Java side

```
l.getGlobal("onUpdate");
l.pushJavaObject(gl);
l.pcall(1, 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you try this instead:

```
gl:glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
```

notice the dot after the second `gl`

This link describes the difference between `.` and `:`

- http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html